# is it possible to read the action value of a form with php?

Tags: php, forms

I'm wondering if there's a way to read, or extract, the value from the action parameter of a form tag in php?
`<form name="..." method="post" action="*this*">`

This code return each value of each element inside the form, but not from the `form`-tag itself:

```
foreach($_POST as $_FORM_value){
    $_FORM_values[] = $_FORM_value;
}
```

Any ideas?

Now I'm just using a hidden field to execute the correct script:

```
<input type="hidden" name="load-script" value="ScriptName" readonly>
```

And at the very top, before hta page is starting to load and any html is sent to the client, I'm checking to se if any form has been submittet:

```
if(isset($_POST['load-script'])){include dir_setup.'post.exec.php';}
```

And inside **post.exec.php**:

```
#   get name from submit-button
    foreach($_POST as $_FORM_ELEMENT_name=>$_FORM_ELEMENT_value){
        if (!strncmp($_FORM_ELEMENT_name,'submit_',7)){
            $_FORM_ELEMENT_submit_name=explode('_',$_FORM_ELEMENT_name);
            $_FORM_name=$_FORM_ELEMENT_submit_name[1];
        }
    }
//
#   fetch script
    if(empty($_POST['load-script'])){
        $_SITE_notices[] = '<code><b>load-script</b></code> in <code><b>'.$_FORM_name.'</b></code> is empty.';
    }else{
        $_FORM_SCRIPT=$_POST['load-script'].'.script.php';  //  script to search for.
        if(file_exists(dir_scripts.$_FORM_SCRIPT)){  //  check locally first.
            include dir_scripts.$_FORM_SCRIPT;  //  include script from local folder - if found.
        }else{  //  script was not found locally.
            if($_SITE_FRAMEWORK){
                if(file_exists(ROOT_FRAMEWORK.dir_scripts.$_FORM_SCRIPT)){  //  check framework.
                    include ROOT_FRAMEWORK.dir_scripts.$_FORM_SCRIPT;  //  include script from framework - if found.
                }else{  //  script was not found in either directory; quit searching and throw error.
                    $_SITE_notices[] = 'Could not locate <code><b>'.$_FORM_SCRIPT.'</b></code> in either <code><small>&lt;ROOT&gt;</small><b>/'.dir_scripts.'</b></code> or <code><small>&lt;FRAMEWORK&gt;</small><b>/'.dir_scripts.'</b></code>';
                }
            }else{  //  framework is not activated; quit searching and throw error.
                $_SITE_notices[] = 'Could not locate <code><b>'.$_FORM_SCRIPT.'</b></code> in <code><small>&lt;ROOT&gt;</small><b>/'.dir_scripts.'</b></code>';
            }
        }
    }
//
```

My idea was to eliminate the need for the hidden load-script element, and just use the form action value to determen which script to load. But that might not be possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `action` defines the url of the script to be called. Therefore You can see all action's details in some `$_SERVER` variables - maybe `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will be useful for You.

Comment: Not to be too picky - but those values are just what Apache 'sees'. Both may be altered by HTTP redirects, rewrite rules or whatnot. There is no guarantee whatsoever that these values correspond to original HTML fields.

Comment: You are correct, they will definitely *not* contain exactly the string from the `action="..."`. ThomasK wants to "use the form action value to determen which script to load" and maybe he finds `$_SERVER[something]` useful enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, by its very definition submitting a form only serializes all the values of the `form` in question and sends those to the server by the defined `method`. In PHP you can check exactly what is in a postback with:

```
var_dump($_POST);     // assuming POST method
```

No other data from your HTML is returned whatsoever.

[Relevant section in the HTML5 standards to be found here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0), specifically the [form data set construction logic](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set).